# jQuery: How to get the value of an html attribute?

Tags: jquery

I've got an html anchor element:

```
<a title="Some stuff here">Link Text</a>
```

...and I want to get the contents of the title so I can use it for something else:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var title = $(this).getTheTitleAttribute();
    alert(title);
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(title);
});
```

Comment: @KolobCanyon `prop` is to be used with properties (like `disabled`, `readonly`, etc) `attr` is for attributes (`attribute=value`). Properties do not contain values, they are active be their presence alone, i.e. `<input disabled/>` properties contain values `<input attribute=value/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).attr("title")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `this.title` inside the function

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var myTitle = $(this).attr ( "title" ); // from jQuery object
    //var myTitle = this.title; //javascript object
    alert(myTitle);
});
```

***Note***

Use another variable name instead of 'alert'. Alert is a javascript function and don't use it as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

You can create function and pass this function from onclick event

```
<a onclick="getTitle(this);" title="Some stuff here">Link Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getTitle(el)
{
     title = $(el).attr('title');
     alert(title);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Even you can try this, if you want to capture every click on the document and get attribute value:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    var value = $(event.target).attr('id');
    alert(value);
});
```