# How to compare the attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to compare the attribute value in jQuery?

example

```
if( $(this).[ attribute value ] == "0")
{}
else
{}
```

Comment: You should probably consider reading a basic jQuery tutorial, and reviewing the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to get the value of an html attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845041/jquery-how-to-get-the-value-of-an-html-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get the attribute value:

```
if ($(this).attr("myAttr") == "0") {
    // "myAttr" value is "0"
} else {
    // "myAttr" value is not "0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).attr("yourAttribute") == "0"){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I forgot to keep 0 in quotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if( $(this).attr('myattribute') == "0")    
{
   //Your statements
}    
else    
{
   //Your statements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute value using the `attr` method and compare it:

```
if ($(this).attr("attrname") == "0") {
  $(this).css('background', 'red');
}
```

You can also use a selector to filter out elements with a specific attribute value:

```
$(this).filter('[attrname=0]').css('background', 'red');
```