# How to find the value in the max attribute of input element

Tags: jquery, html

How to find the value in the max attribute of input element using **Jquery**

```
<input type="number" id="pageNumber" class="toolbarField pageNumber" value="1" size="4" min="1" tabindex="7" max="29">
```

I tried

```
$("input[max]").val()
```

But it didn't help

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to get the value of an html attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845041/jquery-how-to-get-the-value-of-an-html-attribute)

Answer (score 20):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to get the value of max attribute.

**[Live Demo](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
$('#pageNumber').attr('max');
```

Comment: Beware that although the API documentation states that they may return a Number, `attr('max')` and `val()` seem to return strings when used on a number input type element (jquery-1.12.3).

Comment: Yes. So better  `parseInt()`  it.

Answer (score 9):

Use attr() for  find the value of an attribute

Try this

```
$(".toolbarField").attr("max");
```

or

```
$('#pageNumber').attr('max');
```

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").attr("max");
```

This gets the value of the attribute

See the jQuery API Document for it: http://api.jquery.com/attr/