# How do I get min and max values from a slider in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the min and max values from my slider:

```
<input class="slider" data-spanid="span1" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0">
```

What I've tried with jQuery:

```
let min = $(".slider").eq(i).min;
let max = $(".slider").eq(i).max;
```

If I console.log the min or max variables it returns "undefined"

```js
let min = $(".slider").eq(i).min;
let max = $(".slider").eq(i).max;
console.log(max);
console.log(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="slider" data-spanid="span1" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0">
```

Comment: Try [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Why are you using `eq(i)`? Are there multiple sets of min/max sliders in your page?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I am using multiple sliders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
let min = $(".slider").prop('min');
let max = $(".slider").prop('max');
```

Answer (score 1):

though your question might be duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582184/how-to-find-the-value-in-the-max-attribute-of-input-element/14582272)

try this

```js
 
let min = $(".slider").attr("min");;
let max = $(".slider").attr("max");;
console.log(`max : ${max}`);
console.log(`min : ${min}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="slider" data-spanid="span1" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0">
```