# How to store the value of an attribute inside a variable using html, javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a line `<meta property="product:price:amount" content="3.05"/>`
 in a large html file.

I need to  store the value of `content` inside a variable, so that I may access it globally. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Have have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: [jQuery: How to get the value of an html attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845041/jquery-how-to-get-the-value-of-an-html-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To very specifically get the meta tag you are after (event if there are multiple meta tags):

```
var variable = document.querySelectorAll('meta[property="product:price:amount"]')[0].content;
```

Comment: Great answer but why `.querySelectorAll()` to only set `[0`], would it not be just as easy to use `document.querySelector('meta[property="product:price:amount"]').content;`

Comment: absolutely! habit i guess

Answer (score 3):

Just catch it with `querySelector` to get it's `content` attribute.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('meta').content;

console.log(content);
```

```html
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="3.05"/>
```

In case of multiple `meta` tags:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('meta');

let content = Array.from(elems).find(v => v.content).content;

console.log(content);
```

```html
<meta property="product:price:amount"/>
<meta property="product:price:amount"/>
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="3.05"/>
```

Comment: that would not be very specific considering you have multiple meta elements right?

Comment: @hansTheFranz That's a higher level of abstraction, which requires another solution. In this specific case, that's a complete needed solution.

Comment: What's the need for `let content = elem.content;`. Why can't I just do `console.log(elem)`

Comment: @kashish Then you will log whole `meta` element. If you really want to log it - `console.log(elem.content)`.

Answer (score 0):

For a single meta tag:

```js
var myGlobal = document.querySelector('meta[content]').getAttribute('content');
document.body.textContent = myGlobal;
```

```html
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="3.05"/>
```

If you have a lot of tags:

```js
var contentArray = [];
document.querySelectorAll('meta[content]').forEach(function(meta){
  contentArray.push(meta.getAttribute('content'));
});
document.body.textContent = contentArray.join(' - ');
```

```html
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="3.05"/>
<meta property="product:quality:amount" content="9.25"/>
<meta property="product:id:amount" content="1.0"/>
```

If you want to be more specific about the tag you can change the selector:

```
...querySelector('meta[property="product:price:amount"][content]')...
```

Read more about selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors

Comment: updated the answer to handle both cases. he does say that he have "a line", but it's there to help other ppl.

Comment: I mean other meta tags such as: Description, Keywords, Author ect.... `<meta name="description" content="Meta tag exmaple">` => `<meta name="keywords" content="Meta, example">` => `<meta name="author" content="John Smith">`

Comment: the updated code will handle all meta tags that have a content attribute.

Comment: Exactly my point. I don't think the OP wants the variable to hold the description, author and other meta tag data...

Comment: then all they gotta do is to change the selector. not a big deal I guess

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one item then simply

```
document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0].content
```